# Query an XSD for node details using XPath

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xsd

Is there a Perl module that will load an XSD and allow an XPath query to return details e.g. the type of `/MemberDetails/MemberNumber`, whether it is optional, repeating, and so on.

My use case is to convert a CSV file to XML, I have been given an XSD along with a mapping file that lists the input field position and output XPath value.

The mapping file does not specify which fields are repeatable so constructing the data structure for `XML::Compile::Schema` is troublesome. I could manually add the details for each field however I'd prefer to avoid this.

My current thoughts are to split the XPath expression then use something like `$xsd = $schema->template('TREE' => $type)` and walk through it, examining the type at each level of the structure. But this feels like a fairly clunky and risky way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use xsd just like any other xml file and get attributes and so on. So the same tools are capable of doing that:

- XML::XPath (old)
- XML::LibXML (preferable)

LibXML can also validate your xml result against that xsd (whether it is valid).

Comment: True I can use XPath on the XSD however the layout is quite complex with a lot of indirection. Breaking an XPath query into component elements and then following the definitions of named complex types will be quite a bit of work when there are XSD parsers capable of doing this already. If I'm generating the XML I also need to know the intermediate types to build the structure for XML::Compile::Schema so I can't just search for the type of the deepest node. See for example the last XSD at http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve: you want to get parameters of each specific node in xsd? or you want to create xml file that is valid against some xsd?
Maybe this will suite you better: XML::Pastor

Comment: both actually. XML::Compile::Schema will load the XSD and let you pass in a perl hash. It will validate and translate the hash to XML. It's very simple but you need to know the properties of each node in your program (e.g. array for collection). I was hoping to have the program query these node properties to automate the structure building since they are just giving me a value and final XPath address, I don't know which nodes in between are collections etc. XML::Pastor seems interesting, I have never seen it but will try to get it working (our Perl is old and on Windows).